# How JavaScript works facing with string numbers

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how JavaScript interpret the string numbers (i.e. "2"). for instance:

```
var car = { color: "red", model: "370"};
var anotherAge = ++(car.model) + 2;
```

or

```
var b=+"1" + 2; // returns 3
```

How JavaScript really works when it use ++("370")? I am looking for the way JavaScript behaves. What happens beyond?

Comment: Some numeric operators coerce their arguments to numbers before doing what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically works like this:

```
var anotherAge = ++(car.model) + 2;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               coerce to numeric -> int(371)

var b=+"1" + 2;
//    ^
//    coerce to numeric -> int(1)
```

Once converted to a numeric expression, the remaining `+` operation will be interpreted as a mathematical operation rather than string concatenation.